# How to loop in Excel to apply GPOs list to OUs in Powershell

Tags: powershell, gpo

I need to loop through an Excel file for OUs and GPOs then apply them to the GPO Management Console. I'm stuck for understand the loop process.

```
get-module activedirectory,grouppolicy
#Open Excel and read info in file
$filepath = "C:\temp\AllGPOsLinkWin10toApply-report date 13-05-2019.xlsx"
$sheetname = "AllGPOsWin10 date 13-05"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $false
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($filepath)
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.Sheets.Item($sheetname)
$OU = @{}
$destinationOU = @{}
$i = 1
$j= 2

#Read the OU cells (A,$i) column 1, row 1 to 13
$destinationOU = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($i, 1).Text

#Read the GPO cells (all cells to the right of the OU cell)
#then loop and apply each GPO to the OU until cells are empty
$GPO = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($i+1, $j).Text

set-GPLink -Name $GPO -Target $destinationOU -LinkEnabled yes
i = i + 1
#Loop all OUs cells in column A and start again the process
```

Comment: You dont have a loop in your code. A loop looks like that `for ($i=0;$i -lt $WorkSheet.Cells.Count;$i++) {
    #But here your code like $destione = blabla
}` And you don't need to increase $i, it's already defined in the loop. Just google how to do a for loop in powershell

Comment: Thanks but I've already tested some and am stuck, I presented the code without any loop but made comments of what I'd like to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest this:

```
#Loop from row 1 to 13
for ($row = 1; $row -le 13; $row++) {

$destinationOU = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($row, 1).Text 

#Read all the cells to right of column 2 (until an empty cell is found)
$col = 2   
while (($WorkSheet.Cells.Item($row, $col).Text) -ne "") {
    $GPO = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($row, $col).Text
    set-GPLink -Name $GPO -Target $destinationOU -LinkEnabled yes
    $col++  
    }
}
```

It may be safer to loop through the used range:

```
for ($row = 1; $row -le $WorkSheet.UsedRange.Row.Count; $row++) {

$destinationOU = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($row, 1).Text 

for ($col = 2; $col -le $WorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count; $col++) {
    $GPO = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($row, $col).Text
    set-GPLink -Name $GPO -Target $destinationOU -LinkEnabled yes
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Benoit, I was able to get it working with your help. Very much appreciated help :-) Have a pleasant day